# Database-value vs user-input textbox

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have this email sending function and was wondering if there's a thing I can do to change the database entry to user input. To give an example, here's what I did to my initialization.

```
txtEmailAddress.Text = account.Email;
```

then on my aspx view:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtEmailAddress" runat="server" />

<asp:Button ID="btnSendMail" runat="server" Text="Send" onclick="btnSendMail_Click" />
```

Upon clicking the send button, it doesn't change whenever I want to send an email to other email address with this line

```
mailMessage.To.Add(txtEmailAddress.Text);
```

Comment: The question is not clear to me. Do you want to change `txtEmailAddress.Text` before adding `mailMessage.To`?

Comment: Hi @SelimYıldız, yes

Comment: So you just need definew new variable like: `var emailAddress = txtEmailAddress.Text;
emailAddress = "newEmail@domain.com";
mailMessage.To.Add(emailAddress);` then?

Comment: It should send then to the emailAddress. What I'm targeting is using the same email function whether or not the user has edited the txtEmailAddress

Comment: So, don't allow to user change this txtEmailAddress with adding Enable attribute :`<asp:TextBox Enabled="false"  ID="txtEmailAddress" runat="server" />` or get information from `account.Email;` instead.

Comment: My bad, my words might've made it more confusing. My dilemma is user should have the option to replace the email address if he/she does not want to send it to `account.Email`

Comment: You are not sending user input to `account.Email`, are you? You are just initialize your textbox from `account.Email` and adding txtEmailAddress.Text to your list of mail. So what do you mean "if he/she does not want to send it to account.Email" by that.

Comment: If he/she wants to change the textbox.text to his/her own email rather than the initialized content. Apparently, once I hit the send button, it would still use the one I initialized rather than the new one I've entered

Comment: So, please provide more info about send button that you mentioned.